# How to efficiently append values to a dataframe and give a column name?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a row of data (my_row) for which I would like to add new column and fill this column with a number from a specific position in another dataframe (df). At the same time I would like to give this column a name ("m5").

Please find, below, my data:

```
my_row <- data.frame(m1 = c(1), 
                     m2 = c(4), 
                     m3 = c(3), 
                     m4 = c(3))
  
  
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3), 
                 x2 = c(4,1,6), 
                 x3 = c(3,0,2), 
                 x4 = c(3,0,1))
```

I can reach my goal with the code below, although this looks quite cumbersome to me. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
library(dplyr)
  
my_number <- as.data.frame(df$x2[2])
colnames(my_number)[1] <- "m5"
my_row <- dplyr::bind_cols(my_row, my_number)


my_row
   m1 m2 m3 m4 m5
1  1  4  3  3  1
```

Answer (score 3):

Base R:

```
my_row$m5 <- df$x2[2]
my_row
```

```
  m1 m2 m3 m4 m5
1  1  4  3  3  1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `mutate()`.

```
library(dplyr)

my_row %>% mutate(m5 = df$x2[2])

 m1 m2 m3 m4 m5
1  1  4  3  3  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just `cbind` in `base R`, if we don't want to to update the original object

```
cbind(my_row, m5 = df$x2[2])
  m1 m2 m3 m4 m5
1  1  4  3  3  1
```

Comment: @ TarJae @benson23 Thank you all for your solutions! I have a slight preference for the dplyr solution since I try to use tidyverse solutions where possible. I suppose these solutions are most error resistant in combination with other code if i am correct. Although I am not sure, so it is hard to select the best answer in this case.